# Is it possible for one group of devs to use pipenv venvs and for other use conda venvs on the same project?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, pipenv

In our project we split in our choice of conda and pipenv environments. Is it possible that every developer uses the environment-provider of his choice without breaking the setup of another?

E.g. is it possible to make conda use Pipfiles? Or pipenv use condas environments under the hood and still use the Pipfiles.

We really want to go from requirements.txt to Pipfiles, but some do not want to abandon conda venvs.

Comment: maybe add a hook to generate `requirements.txt` from a pipfile for backward compatibility?

Comment: @Marat how do I implement that? Sounds like an interesting choice, thought I would if possible avoid using requirements.txt altogether.

Comment: [This discussion](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3493) has a lot of practical advises how to do that. The idea is to get rid of `requirements.txt` in version control and only generate it locally for people who want to stick with classic venv